# How to process lines in a file in specific hadoop slave?

Tags: dictionary, split, hadoop

We have a custom input format extending the FileInputFormat, which generates a separate split for each line in the input file. This file provides a host name in which the mapper handling this line should run.

How do I achieve this?

This is needed as the mapper reads data from DB and I want to run the mapper in the same machine as the DB server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible without writing your own implementation within the Hadoop code base.

If you are trying to add more data to the map input then pass it in as an argument to the job and you can then have it in your map() and concatenate it with the input.

Comment: I'm trying to schedule each map to a specific node.

Comment: Even something which allows me to put each line of the input file on a specific host will help as that will make Hadoop run the map on the same host as the input line.

Comment: Not possible without writing your own implementation within the Hadoop code base.

Comment: Hadoop use data localization and opens the map split wherever it is replicated too for performance benefit however it wants to do it.  It also will start multiple maps and reduces (even if it is already doing it) so whichever finishes first wins and kills the others.